# Is cuMemAllocHost numa aware?

Tags: cuda

If a system has two CPUs and 4 graphics cards and if each pair of cards are connected a different CPU, does cuMemAllocHost command for a gpu allocate from closest CPU node to that GPU?

Can pinned arrays(either with cudaHostRegister or cuMemAllocHost) be looked from closest pci-e path always?

If its not numa aware, can I trust OS capabilities on this and have lowest access latencies on any system that is using same OS as development system?

Comment: It is unlikely someone with first-hand knowledge will answer this. You could use a system-level trace (e.g. `strace`) to find out what happens behind the scenes. To my *very limited* knowledge, these CUDA functions are *thin* wrappers around standard OS functionality such as `mmap` and as such unlikely to be NUMA aware, meaning you would want to control memory and processor affinity with `numactl` or an equivalent tool to ensure each GPU communicates with the "near" CPU and it's attached "near" memory.

Comment: if I am going to distribute some CUDAfied program, then will I need batch command files to do numactl with it?

Comment: How is this CUDA-specific?  How is it any different than asking how to enforce [processor-memory affinity](http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html)?   If you know which socket your GPU is attached to, you know which socket you want memory allocations to be performed on.

Comment: So you say OpenMP can do that or I have to do process-level binding instead of in-process binding. I wanted to know if CUDA driver api commands can have control over numa or not.

Comment: The short answer is CUDA doesn't provide any NUMA controls.  If you want to ask about OpenMP, perhaps you should do that with a question that is tagged with `openmp` and not `cuda`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA doesn't provide NUMA controls.

Management of NUMA may certainly be important for achieving highest performance of CUDA codes, and should follow [standard methods](http://www.glennklockwood.com/hpc-howtos/process-affinity.html) which are orthogonal to CUDA programming.